# Configuring ASP.NET application to always accept GET request from a particular IP address?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an application that's locked down using forms authentication. There are few nightly tasks I want to script that make get requests to, say, http://myapp.domain.com/NightlyTask ... I don't need any response, I just need it to accept a get request from a certain IP address. I realize you could spoof an IP address, etc. but I'm trying to make this dead simple.

Is there anyway I can setup the Web.config to unconditionally give access to a certain IP? Any other idea to approach this?

Again, long-term solution would be a service running Quartz or some other cron-like job handler. I'm not quite there yet, hoping for an interim solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not recommended for various security reasons but if you must, you can create your own authorization filter

```
public class AuthFilter : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UserHostAddress == "127.0.0.1")
            return;

        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }
}
```

you would substitute 127.0.0.1 for your ip and this would work.